# Differential Equations: Can someone detail out the exact steps for a question like this?

Tags: calculus

This is a sample question. I am hoping it will clear a few basic concepts. I have many questions like these that I have no idea how to solve.

[image]

For now, I can't even do part i. I think I'll be able to do part ii on my own if I can get to part i.

I am very new to differential equations, and have to give an exam on it this week -- I am self-taught and have no teachers or peers, so please bear with me. My question is no doubt very basic, but I believe that if I can get these basics straight, I'll be able to solve most problems like these.

I do think this is one of those moments where the only way I can figure this out is by someone, in very step-by-step manner, detailing out the exact process for this question (I can't "try" anything, and I've spent a lot of time on these trying to get the equation). I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hint: dh/dt is the rate at which the depth of water is changing. Net Rate = Rate of increase - Rate of decrease. Rate of increase = Volume increase per second / Area of the base. Assume Rate of decrease = C√h. Find the value of C using the given condition.

Answer (score 1):

The volume $V$ of the reservoir is givent by $V=Ah(t)$, where $A=1000\,m^2$ is the reservoir horizontal area, and $h(t)$ is the height of the water in the reservoir, which is a function of time. The rate of change of the volume of water in the reservoir is $dV/dt$ (i.e. the definition of the derivative). This rate of change is the sum of the rater of water flowing in $W_{in} = 30\,m^3/s$ and the rate of the water flowing out that we know to be $W_{out}=C\sqrt{h}$, i.e. proportional to $\sqrt{h}$. Note that $C$ must have dimensions of $m^{5/2}/s$. Putting all together we can write:
$$
\dfrac{dV}{dt}=W_{in}-W_{out}
$$

which can be transformed to
$$
A\dfrac{dh}{dt}=30\dfrac{m^3}{s}-C\sqrt{h}
$$
To determine $C$ we know that $dh/dt = 0.02\,m/s$ when $h=1\,m$. This determine $C=10 \,m^{5/2}/s$.
So the equation can be rearranged (omitting all the measurement units) as:
$$
\dfrac{dh}{dt}=0.01(3-\sqrt{h})
$$

Comment: I got it, I got it! Thank you! I have one more question, if you don't mind answering. I was thinking -- my book gave me the chain rule application at one point. I tried doing that in the middle of solving this: $\frac{dV}{dt}= \frac{dV}{dh} * \frac{dh}{dt}$. This becomes $30 - k\sqrt h = 1000 * \frac{dh}{dt}* \frac{dh}{dt}$, right? Now how do we "square" the $\frac{dh}{dt}$?

Comment: Not sure to catch your question. First, the chain rule is right, but $dV/dh = A= 1000\,m^2$ which gives again my last equation. What do you mean by "square" the $dh/dt$?Solving the equation?